# How to add and pop a widget like this in flutter for showing cart items

Tags: android, flutter, dart, widget

I am building a project on flutter consisting of two apps for ordering food inside the college and I want to add this functionality in my code how do I do this . if you provide proper code along with explanation it will be pretty helpful

[when we are at menu of the selected resturant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dX8dq.jpg)

[when item is added through add button can be done I think using showbottom sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUSVt.jpg)

[the widget I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOESC.jpg)
(This is what I don't know how to execute such that it changes when each item is added or subtracted also navigated to cart screen and gets removed automatically when all the added items are removed)

I tried show bottom sheet but could not execute it well and I don't think that has to be used here

Comment: can you include sample code-snippet

Comment: you can use stack and visibility widget to achieve this.
stack your main ui and cart container, wrap your cart container with visibility,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.